# Parsing JSON Object - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm struggling to see why this code is not working. I have many other views using different JSON services. All working normally. However, this one is simply not. I retrieve the values back from the service as I expect however when trying to loop over it (see below code) the Array is Nil. Clearly something simple I have missed but I have been looking at this issue far to long.

Abstract View of JSON service;

```
    {
    "0": {
        "altitude": "14500",
        "latitude": "41.41555",
        "longitude": "-73.09605",
        "realname": "David KGNV"
    },
    "1": {
        "altitude": "61",
        "latitude": "33.67506",
        "longitude": "-117.86739",
        "realname": "Mark CT"
    },
    "10": {
        "altitude": "38161",
        "latitude": "40.51570",
        "longitude": "-93.25554",
        "realname": "Bob CYYZ"
    },
    "100": {
        "altitude": "33953",
        "latitude": "52.35600",
        "longitude": "5.30384",
        "realname": "Jim LIRQ"
    }
}
```

Abstract view of the JSON call;

*Note the NSArray *currentMapArray valueKeyPath is set to "" as I need all elements within the JSON result.

```
  NSError *_errorJson = nil;
         jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

         if (_errorJson != nil) {
             NSLog(@"Error %@", [_errorJson localizedDescription]);
         } else {
             //Do something with returned array
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 NSDictionary *mapJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

                 //Loop through the JSON array
                 NSArray *currentMapArray = [mapJson valueForKeyPath:@""];

                 //set up array and json call
                 mapArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


                 for (int i = 0; i< currentMapArray.count; i++)
                 {
                     //create our object
                     NSString *nAltitude = [[currentMapArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"altitude"];
                     NSString *nRealname = [[currentMapArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"realname"];
                     NSString *nLatitude = [[currentMapArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitude"];
                     NSString *nLongitude = [[currentMapArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"longitude"];

                     [mapArray addObject:[[LiveVatsimMap alloc]initWithaltitude:nAltitude andrealname:nRealname andlatitude:nLatitude andlongitude:nLongitude]];
                 }
```

The results of currentMapArray is NIL resulting the NSString not being filled out appropriately.

```
for (int i = 0; i< currentMapArray.count; i++)
```

Of course when I hard code the value of JSON node i.e. 10 into the ValueKeyPath then it provides the correct data results and populates accordingly.

Any ideas? Be nice...I'm only new at this objective c stuff.

Comment: Here is your first problem: `error:nil];`

Comment: And YOY do you dispatch an async task to parse the JSON??

Comment: And what do you think this is doing:  `NSArray *currentMapArray = [mapJson valueForKeyPath:@""];` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON doesn't have an array - it is a dictionary of dictionaries.

You can iterate over it using

```
 NSArray *keys=[jsonArray allKeys];
 for (NSString *key in keys) {
     NSDictionary *elementDictionary=jsonArray[key];
     NSString *nAltitude = elementDictionary[@"altitude"];
     NSString *nRealname = elementDictionary[@"realname"];
     NSString *nLatitude = elementDictionary[@"latitude"];
     NSString *nLongitude = elementDictionary[@"longitude"];

     [mapArray addObject:[[LiveVatsimMap alloc]initWithaltitude:nAltitude andrealname:nRealname andlatitude:nLatitude andlongitude:nLongitude]];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Forgot to mention that its cast as an NSMutableArray. Not sure if that changes it or not. I see what you mean though as in you loop over the keys. Still doesn't work entirely, but I think that may be on my end not sure yet.

Comment: Okay I got it. Thanks for your help. I ended up with the following code which seems to work. I just changed the jsonArray to mapJson which is directly from the NSDictionary..duh! Thanks again!

Comment: NSArray *keys=[mapJson allKeys];
                 for (NSString *key in keys) {
                     NSDictionary *elementDictionary=mapJson[key];
                     NSString *nAltitude = elementDictionary[@"altitude"];
                     NSString *nRealname = elementDictionary[@"realname"];
                     NSString *nLatitude = elementDictionary[@"latitude"];
                     NSString *nLongitude = elementDictionary[@"longitude"];
                 }

Comment: @Jeremy, casting an object to an array doesn't make it one, so it makes no difference that you cast it to a mutable array. It is what it is, and casting doesn't change that.